# List all containers in all pods with status

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am trying to get a list of all non-READY containers in all pods to debug a networking issue in my cluster.

Is it possible to use kubectl to get a clean list of all containers in all pods with their status (READY/..)?

I am currently using

```
$ kubectl get pods
```

However, the output can be huge and it can be difficult to know which containers are READY and which ones have issues.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

`kubectl get pods -o=jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{"\n"}{.metadata.name}{":\t"}{range .status.containerStatuses[*]}{.ready}{", "}{end}{end}'`

Adapted from this doc: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/list-all-running-container-images/#list-containers-by-pod

**Edit** to describe what the jsonpath is doing:

From what I understand with the jsonpath, range iterates all of the .items[*] returned by getting the pods. \n is added to split the result to one per line, otherwise the result would come to one line. To see how the rest work, you should choose one of your pods and run:
`kubectl get pod podname -o yaml`
.metadata.name corresponds to

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: podname
```

Similarly, .status.containerStatuses[*] corresponds to the list of container statuses that should be towards the bottom.

Comment: Great answer! In my cluster, some containers are showing up to 3 statuses = true like this: kube-dns-86f4d74b45-cqt6f: true,   true,  true. Some are showing 2 trues like: calico-node-w968t: true,   true. Do you know what that indicates @Joshua Oliphant

Comment: Also, can you explain what's happening in that jsonpath?

Comment: true, true, true means the pod has 3 containers that are each ready

Comment: The command in the answer is adapted from: kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o=jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{"\n"}{.metadata.name}{":\t"}{range .spec.containers[*]}{.image}{", "}{end}{end}' which lists all pods along with the containers in them.

Answer (score 1):

I've adapted [@joshua-oliphant's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54913267/2003325) to include container-names:

`kubectl get pods -o=jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{"\n"}{.metadata.name}{":\t"}{range .status.containerStatuses[*]}{.name}{": "}{.ready}{", "}{end}{end}'`

This will display all pods including all containers in the current namespace with their ready-state such as:

```
pod-name: container-name-a: true, container-name-b: false
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jq, we can list all pods and their containers' statuses:

`kubectl get pods --output=json | jq --raw-output '.items | map([.metadata.name, (.status.containerStatuses | map(.name + ": " + (.ready | tostring)))[]]) | .[] | join("\n  ")'`

This displays something like this:

```
pod-1234-auiend
  container1: true
  container2: false
another-pod-2454-123123:
  container1: true
(...)
```